# map items from list using list comprehension?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, loops

I have a problem with a list comprehension inside a loop. I want to add items from one list to an other.

I'm using `map class` and `zip` inside the list comprehension.

```
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
import pandas
x = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
y = [2, 3, 6, 7, 4]
ser = {'A': Series(x), 'B': Series(y)}
df = DataFrame(ser)
targets = df['A'].tolist()
df['A1999'] = [i + 1 for i in df['B']]
df['A2000'] = [i + 2 for i in df['B']]
df['A2001'] = [i + 3 for i in df['B']]
df['A2002'] = [i + 1.7 for i in df['B']]
df['A2003'] = [i + 1.1 for i in df['B']]
y = range(1999, 2004)
gaps = []
for t in targets:
    temp = []
    years = []
    for ele in y:
        target = 'A' + str(ele)
        new = df[target][df['A'] == t].tolist()
        temp.append(new)
        years.append(ele)
        gap = [list(map(list, zip(years, item))) for item in temp]
    gaps.append(gap)
```

And the output:

```
[[[[1999, 3]], [[1999, 4]], [[1999, 5]], [[1999, 3.7000000000000002]],
  [[1999, 3.1000000000000001]]]...
```

What I'm looking for is:

```
[[[[1999, 3]], [[2000, 4]], [[2001, 5]], [[2002, 3.7000000000000002]],
  [[2003, 3.1000000000000001]]]...
```

How can I fix the list comprehension in order to add all years from `years list` and not only the first (i.e. 1999)

**I tried** with this example, but I think I'm doing the same thing:

```
gap = [[[years[i], x] for i, x in enumerate(y)] for y in temp]
```

or

```
gap = [list(map(list, zip([[y] for y in years], item))) for item in temp]
```

Comment: Inside your second loop `for ele in y` you assign lots of values to gap but only add the last one (as `gaps.append(gap)` is outside the loop. Is that supposed to be this way?

Comment: Also for example is this item `[[2000, 4]]` what you really need (as opposed to `[2000, 4]`)?

Comment: Yes. `gaps.append(gap)` must be outside, the other way all `gap` will be as years `lenght`, what I want is targets `lenght`

Comment: @CristiFati actually you're right. `[2000, 4]` should be the right output. In order to `append` results from `gap` I used an empty list `gaps = []` That's why the output is different :S

Comment: Your example code doesn't run

Comment: if this is right, edit your question so it is clearer. `import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 'B': [2, 3, 6, 7, 4]}, columns=['A','B'])

df['A1999'] = df['B'] + 1

gaps = []`

Comment: `df['A1999'] = [i + 1 for i in df['B']] # to A2003` As it is an example code, I didn't add `df['A2000']` `df['A2001']` `df['A2002']` `df['A2003']`

Comment: I am finding it difficult to understand what you are trying to do. The first thing I need is a working example. Can you edit your question so it runs?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123179/discussion-between-memebrain-and-estebanpdl).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace gap = with this

```
[list((x,y[0])) for x,y in zip(years,temp)]
```